# Improve long-winded Haskell Monadic code

Tags: haskell, monads, composition, yesod

The following function, part of a Yesod REST server, searches a MongoDB database for a existing user by email address and returns a `Maybe User`:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

module Model.User where

import           Database.MongoDB (Action, findOne, select, (=:))
import qualified Database.MongoDB as M
import           GHC.Generics     (Generic)
import           Import

data User = User
  { userEmail     :: Text
  , userFirstName :: Text
  , userLastName  :: Text
  } deriving (Generic, Show)

collection :: Text
collection = "users"

instance FromJSON User
instance ToJSON User

findForEmail :: Text -> Action IO (Maybe User)
findForEmail email = do
  maybeDocument <- findOne (select [ "email" =: email ] collection)
  case maybeDocument of
    Just document -> do
      email' <- M.lookup "email" document
      firstName <- M.lookup "firstName" document
      lastName <- M.lookup "lastName" document
      return $ Just $ User email' firstName lastName
    Nothing       -> return Nothing
```

The part involving the two "nested" monads (`maybeDocument <-`) feels very "long-winded". `findOne` returns a `Maybe Document` and `lookup` returns a `Maybe v`.

Can this be shortened, maybe using applicatives?

**UPDATE**

I shortened it to this:

```
maybeDocument <- findOne (select [ "email" =: email ] collection)
case maybeDocument of
  Just document ->
    return $ User <$> M.lookup "email" document
                  <*> M.lookup "firstName" document
                  <*> M.lookup "lastName" document
  Nothing       -> return Nothing
```

but it still feels heavy. Is there any way to combine the `maybeDocument <-` monad with the `lookup`s?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`case` on a `Maybe`, with `Just` mapping to another `Maybe` and `Nothing` immediately to `Nothing`, is the same as using one monadic bind. (Of course you need to keep the `return` out, which acts in the wrong monad here.)

```
   maybeDocument <- findOne (select [ "email" =: email ] collection)
   return $ maybeDocument >>= \document ->
             User <$> M.lookup "email" document
                  <*> M.lookup "firstName" document
                  <*> M.lookup "lastName" document
```

Also, the `maybeDocument` variable is a bit awkward, we can eliminate that: note that, because the result is merely `return`ed into the `Action IO` monad, you don't really need a `do` block at all: you're merely `Functor`-mapping over the result! That can nicely be done point-free:

```
   fmap (>>= \document ->
             User <$> M.lookup "email" document
                  <*> M.lookup "firstName" document
                  <*> M.lookup "lastName" document
        ) $ findOne (select [ "email" =: email ] collection)
```

You may argue this would look a bit nicer if we could preserve the original "evaluation order". We can, using the (nonstandard) [reverse apply operator](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=f+a++-%3E+%28a-%3Eb%29+-%3E+f+b)

```
      findOne (select [ "email" =: email ] collection)  <&>  (>>=
         \document -> User <$> M.lookup "email" document
                           <*> M.lookup "firstName" document
                           <*> M.lookup "lastName" document  )
```

Granted, this makes it rather hard to grasp what each operator is doing, but I think the overall intention is IMO very clear in such concise code.

Comment: Thanks! That's very elegant.